# How to Display Ads/Banners based on location

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using admob to display ads on my app. I want to display ads based on user location(Relevant ads for a locality inside a particular city).

I found a method to send lat/long for admob server.

```
- (void)setLocationWithLatitude:(CGFloat)latitude longitude:(CGFloat)longitude
                       accuracy:(CGFloat)accuracyInMeters;
```

But it may refine ads up to city level & not locality inside a city.

SO any one plz let me know how to achieve this. Other than admob is also acceptable.I dint even find this option in iAds as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Does AdMob state that they have ads for different parts of the same city?  It doesn't seem likely that they would have anything that local since they are a worldwide network.